# JavaScript com dois laços for

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de deixar meu script com select e checkbox's alinhados, mas não estou conseguindo, primeiro vem os valores dos options e depois os check's.
Por exemplo: 10 DESTINOA_111222 DESTINOB_111222 DESTINOD_222333, mas o certo que eu gostaria seria:

1 DESTINOA_111222 DESTINOB_111222 
0 DESTINOD_222333

Segue abaixo o script que estou tratando, acho que o for e a concatenações estão erradas em algum ponto, segue abaixo:

```js
  <script language="javascript">
    
   function obterMarcados() {  
  var resultado_checks = "";
  var listaMarcados = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  
  var all_select   = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  for (loop = 0; loop < listaMarcados.length; loop++) {  
   var resultado_status = "";
   var item = listaMarcados[loop];  
   if (item.type == "checkbox" && item.checked) {  
    resultado_checks += " " + item.id;
   }  
   for (i = 0; i < all_select.length; i++) {
    resultado_status += all_select[i].value;
   }
  }
  resultado = resultado_status + resultado_checks ;
  alert(resultado);
  //alert(resultado_checks);
  document.form.txt_recebe.value = resultado_checks; 
 } 
 
</script>

<%
Valor_Destino1 = 111222
Valor_Destino2 = 222333
%>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form" method="post" action="GetCheckBoxNew.asp">
  <input type="hidden" name="txt_recebe" value="" /> 
  <label>Noticia 01: <select name="status" class="font_body">
       <option value="0">Aguardando
       <option value="1">Revisando
       <option value="2">Publicada
      </select> | <input name="item1" type="checkbox" id="DESTINOA_<%=Valor_Destino1%>" value=""/>Item 1</label> |
  <label><input name="item2" type="checkbox" id="DESTINOB_<%=Valor_Destino1%>" value="" />Item 2</label> |
  <label><input name="item3" type="checkbox" id="DESTINOC_<%=Valor_Destino1%>" value="" />Item 3</label>
  <br />
  <label>Noticia 02: <select name="status" class="font_body">
       <option value="0">Aguardando
       <option value="1">Revisando
       <option value="2">Publicada
      </select> | <input name="item4" type="checkbox" id="DESTINOD_<%=Valor_Destino2%>" value="" />Item 4</label> |
  <label><input name="item5" type="checkbox" id="DESTINOE_<%=Valor_Destino2%>" value="" />Item 5</label> |
  <label><input name="item6" type="checkbox" id="DESTINOF_<%=Valor_Destino2%>" value="" />Item 6</label>
  <br />

  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="btn2" id="btn2" value="Verificar Checados" onclick="obterMarcados()"/>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<%
strRecebe = Trim(Request.Form("txt_recebe"))

MinhaArray = Split(strRecebe, " ")

guardaDestinoA = 0
guardaDestinoB = 0
guardaDestinoC = 0
guardaDestinoD = 0
guardaDestinoE = 0
guardaDestinoF = 0



For each inicio in MinhaArray
 Response.Write inicio & "<br>"
 
 If Mid(inicio,1,InStr(inicio,"_")) = "DESTINOA_" Then 
  guardaDestinoA = 1
  Session("Id") = guardaDestinoA
  If Session("Id") <> 1 Then
   guardaDestinoA = 0
  End If
 End If
 'Session("Id") = Session("Id") & guardaDestinoA & "#"
 
 If Mid(inicio,1,InStr(inicio,"_")) = "DESTINOB_" Then 
  guardaDestinoB = 1
  Session("Id") = guardaDestinoB
  If Session("Id") <> 1 Then
   guardaDestinoB = 0
  End If
 End If
 'Session("Id") = Session("Id") & guardaDestinoB & "#"
 
 If Mid(inicio,1,InStr(inicio,"_")) = "DESTINOC_" Then 
  guardaDestinoC = 1
  Session("Id") = guardaDestinoC
  If Session("Id") <> 1 Then
   guardaDestinoC = 0
  End If
 End If
 'Session("Id") = Session("Id") & guardaDestinoC & "#"
 
 If Mid(inicio,1,InStr(inicio,"_")) = "DESTINOD_" Then 
  guardaDestinoD = 1
  Session("Id") = guardaDestinoD
  If Session("Id") <> 1 Then
   guardaDestinoD = 0
  End If
 End If
 'Session("Id") = Session("Id") & guardaDestinoD & "#"
 
 If Mid(inicio,1,InStr(inicio,"_")) = "DESTINOE_" Then 
  guardaDestinoE = 1
  Session("Id") = guardaDestinoE
  If Session("Id") <> 1 Then
   guardaDestinoE = 0
  End If
 End If
 'Session("Id") = Session("Id") & guardaDestinoE & "#"
   
 If Mid(inicio,1,InStr(inicio,"_")) = "DESTINOF_" Then
  guardaDestinoF = 1
  Session("Id") = guardaDestinoF
  If Session("Id") <> 1 Then
   guardaDestinoF = 0
  End If
 End If
 'Session("Id") = Session("Id") & guardaDestinoF & "#"
 
Next

Response.Write ">" & Session("Id") & "<BR>"

Response.Write "Valor do Destino A >" & guardaDestinoA & "<br>"
Response.Write "Valor do Destino B >" & guardaDestinoB & "<br>"
Response.Write "Valor do Destino C >" & guardaDestinoC & "<br>"
Response.Write "Valor do Destino D >" & guardaDestinoD & "<br>"
Response.Write "Valor do Destino E >" & guardaDestinoE & "<br>"
Response.Write "Valor do Destino F >" & guardaDestinoF

%>
```

Obrigado pessoal.

Atenciosamente,
Leandro.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida

Comment: Meu script mostra este alerta: 10 DESTINOA_111222 DESTINOB_111222 DESTINOD_222333, os valores dos status estão vindo primeiro e depois os checkbox's tudo numa linha apenas, eu queria deixar alinhado cada um com seu option e checkbox, dessa forma: 1 DESTINOA_111222 DESTINOB_111222 Primeira linha e depois linha de baixo 0 DESTINOD_222333

Comment: Já tentou dar um <br> depois de cada linha?

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta, separar o código Javascript do HTML e esclarecendo melhor o que está acontecendo? O código ASP é necessário para a pergunta? Se sim, deixe-o mas adicione então a tag `asp` à pergunta..

Answer (score 2):

Se percebi bem o seu problem sugiro que faça assim:

```
function obterMarcados() {

    // ir buscar todos os elementos
    var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#form1 *');

    //criar uma array com cada conjunto
    var conjuntos = [],
        conjunto = [],
        alvos = ['select', 'input'];
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        var el = elementos[i];
        var tagName = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

        // caso esteja no fim
        if (el.type == 'submit') {
            conjuntos.push(conjunto);
            break;
        }

        // se não fôr input ou select saltar a iteração
        if (alvos.indexOf(tagName) == -1) continue;

        if (el.name == 'status' && tagName == 'select') {
            // caso o grupo estar preenchido;
            if (conjunto.length) conjuntos.push(conjunto);
            conjunto = [];
        }
        // preencher o conjunto
        if (tagName == 'select' || el.checked) conjunto.push(tagName == 'select' ? el.value : el.id);
    }      
    var resultado = JSON.stringify(conjuntos);
    document.form.txt_recebe.value = resultado;
}
```

#### jsFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ejyr189/

Nesta sugestão uma array com arrays dentro. E uso o JSON.stringify para fazer dessa array uma string para que possa pôr no input.

O resultado desta função como está aqui é por exemplo:

```
[
    ["1", "DESTINOC_<%=Valor_Destino1%>"],
    ["2", "DESTINOD_<%=Valor_Destino2%>", "DESTINOE_<%=Valor_Destino2%>"]
]
```

COrrendo no seu servidor esses `<%=Valor_Destino2%>` irão naturalmente ser os IDs que o servidor gera.